# JSON Objects between PHP and Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, json

My iPhone app is grabbing a JSON object from a PHP website.

The object on the PHP site has multiple properties that are Integers.

The properties that are retrieved from the database come back from the database (where they are stored as `INT`) look like this in the JSON: `"seatedplayers":"3"`

The properties that are modified in the PHP code look like this in the JSON: `"currentseat":1`

In my Obj-c I am using an NSNumberFormatter to properly format them like this:
`[numFormatter numberFromString:[jsonObject objectForKey:@"seatedplayers"]];` (jsonObject is an `NSDictionary`)

That code works fine on the properties with quotes around the value, but not on the others.  If I add `stringValue` in my Objective-C code it works on the properties without quotes but not the ones with quotes.

Now, my big problem here, is that this app will need to communicate with Sites that I won't personally write, so what code in Objective-C could I write to handle either instance?

***EDIT***
This is how I get the NSDictionary jsonObject.

```
- (NSDictionary *) getJSONObjectFromWebAddress:(NSString *) address {
// Prepare the URL Request
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:address]];

// Perform the request, expecting JSON back
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error;
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
if (!jsonObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

[responseString release];
return jsonObject;
}
```

Comment: stringValue to what? How did you get the NSDictionary with the json values? I personally would use NSScanner, or write something in pure C.

Comment: Added the answer to how I get it as NSDictionary to the question.  I'll look up NSScanner as I don't know what it is.

Comment: Well this is strange, the answer that helped me solve the problem was deleted and I don't remember who the author was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Luckily, both NSString and NSNumber responds to intValue, so you can safely use that.

```
//NSDictionary* myJsonParsed;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[myJsonParsed valueForKey:@"stringOrInt"] intValue]];
```

Comment: Does intValue return an NSNumber? That's what my types are in Objective-C (they are CoreData objects).

Comment: intValue returns a C int. You can create an NSNumber by calling `[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[myJsonParsed valueForKey:@"stringOrInt"] intValue]];`